# Windows Batch Scripts

Tags: windows, iis-7, batch-file, iis-6, iis-5

I have written a windows batch command as follows to install a application silently

> msiexec /q /i ZFPSetup.msi WIXUI_INSTALLDIR="C:\GEHC\" TARGETVDIR="ZFP" WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX=1 /l*v "C:\gehc\log.txt"

but there is a batch file in that application folder which should run at the time of installation. what should i add to above command inorder to invoke that batch file.
as if that batch file doesnt run, the installation is not successfull.

Answer (score 1):

Call the batch file by putting this on the line below

```
call youruninstaller.bat
```

Comment: and what should i do if application is loading that batch file in program files folder at the time of installation. Is there any way to run that batchfile. I just check that applciation and i found that the a WixCustom action is specified on finish button to run that batch file and invoke a listner. but how can we do this in silent installtion .. ?

Comment: well then use the full path with 'call'
call %programfiles%\productname\yourbatch.bat
the errorhandling depends on the batch, if it returns an errorcode you can check ith with something like 'if errorlevel neq 0'
or check if the batch exists first

Comment: msiexec generally returns immediately, so if you want to run a script that is laid down by the installer you will need to use a start command to launch msiexec, to ensure that you don't execute the batch command too quickly.

Comment: webrik & stephen - can u please give me an example ... like lets say the abc. bat is the name of batch file laid by installer  at the time of installation so how should the command will look like ?

Comment: will the command look like this :- msiexec /q /i ZFPSetup.msi WIXUI_INSTALLDIR="C:\GEHC\" TARGETVDIR="ZFP" WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX=1 /l*v "C:\gehc\log.txt" call %programfiles%\productname\abc.bat

Comment: It should be as simple as a 2 line script, the first is your msi command, and the second is `call "%programfiles%\productname\abc.bat"`.

Comment: i have written this script:

Answer (score 1):

Lets asume your MSI file is in "c:\GEHC" and the application is installed in "c:\program files\ZFP"
try this batch:

```
    start /wait msiexec /q /i c:\ZFPSetup.msi WIXUI_INSTALLDIR="C:\GEHC\" TARGETVDIR="ZFP" WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX=1 /l*v "C:\gehc\log.txt"

call "c:\program files\ZFP\abc.bat"
```

you can add errorhandling like this:

```
if errorlevel neq 0 echo ERROR
```

but you have to place errorhandlers right after every command you use in your batch.
you could also check if the batch file exists, if it doesnt, you can asume that the msi didnt install correctly:

```
if not exist "c:\program files\ZFP\abc.bat" echo ERROR
```

get get more examples type 'if /?' in a cmd

Comment: I tried with your script but it is not call the .bat file which is laid by the installer. the installer is created using WIX.        cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop
start /wait msiexec /q /i ZFPSetup.msi INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files (x86)\GE HealthCare" TARGETVDIR="ZFP" WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX=1 /l*v "C:\log.txt"
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\GE HealthCare\StartKaraf.bat"

Comment: the application is also writing to IIS. How can i add this functionality to my batch script. error which i got in my log file is "CustomAction WriteIIS7ConfigChanges returned actual error code 1603". I am now stucked at writing to IIS :(